# How would I count how many events have a certain list item present in Keen IO?

Tags: analytics, keen-io, bigdata

Say my event looks like:

```
purchase = {
   items: ["pickle", "turtle", "lexicon"]
}
```

How do I count how many events have "pickle"?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `equal` operator.

```
var count = new Keen.Query("count", {
  event_collection: "purchases",
  timeframe: "this_14_days",
  filters: [
    {
      property_name: "items",
      operator: "eq",
      property_value: "pickle"
    }
  ]
});
```

From the [API reference for filters & their operators](https://keen.io/docs/api/#filters):

“Equal to” – Note that if your property’s value is an array, “eq” can be used to filter for values inside that array. For example, eq: 5 will match a value of [5, 6, 7].